# Invalid initialization of non-const reference of type std::_Bit_rerefence&

Tags: c++, stdvector

Uhm, I was writing a code to convert two strings to a bitset (unfortunately `std::bitset` cannot be used due to it's compile time template constant size requirement).

For some reason I cannot reference iterate for range based loop:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::string line;
    std::getline(std::cin, line);

    std::string chips;
    std::string pattern;

    std::istringstream issline(line);
    issline >> chips;
    issline >> pattern;

    auto toBool = [](const char c) -> bool { return(c == 'B'); };
    std::vector<bool> bitchips;
    for(auto& i : chips){
        bitchips.push_back(toBool(i));
    }
    std::vector<bool> bitpattern;
    for(auto& i: pattern){
        bitpattern.push_back(toBool(i));
    }

    auto flip = [&bitchips]() -> void
    {
        for(auto& i : bitchips) { //error
            i = !i;
        }
    };

    return 0;
}
```

`error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'std::_Bit_reference&' from an rvalue of type 'std::_Bit_iterator::reference {aka std::_Bit_reference}'`

What program is doing so far:

Reading user input: `BBBBNNNB NNNBBBNB`. Converting to: `11110001 00011101`

Comment: `std::vector<bool>` is special. Use `auto i : bitchips`.

Comment: Or just use `std::vector<char>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`std::vector<bool>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool) is a specialization of `std::vector`, it behaves different with normal `std::vector`. Especially, `std::vector<bool>::reference` is a proxy class.

> proxy class representing a reference to a single bool

You might use rvalue reference instead. e.g.

```
auto flip = [&bitchips]() -> void
{
    for(auto&& i : bitchips) {
        i = !i;
    }
};
```

or

```
auto flip = [&bitchips]() -> void
{
    for(auto i : bitchips) {
        i = !i;
    }
};
```

or

```
auto flip = [&bitchips]() -> void
{
    for(auto i : bitchips) {
        i.flip();
    }
};
```

even they look counterintuitive.